# Rotation of square by center using rotation matrix

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I'm trying to rotate a square using rotation matrix with this implementation.

```cpp
void Square::rotateVertices(std::vector<float> &vertices)
{
   float px = (vertices[0]+vertices[2])/2;
   float py = (vertices[1]+vertices[5])/2;        
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
       float x1 = vertices[i*2];
       float y1 = vertices[i*2+1];
       vertices[i * 2] = px + (x1 -px)*cos(angle) - (y1 -py)*sin(angle);
       vertices[(i * 2) + 1] = py + (x1 -px)*sin(angle) + (y1 -py)*cos(angle);
    }
}
```

Vertices are calculated using code below:

```cpp
float ay = (size / float(height) / 2.f), ax = (size / float(width) / 2.f);
std::vector<float> vertices = {
            2 * (((x) - float(width) / 2) / float(width)) - ax, 2 * ((y - float(height)) / float(height)) - ay + 1.0f,
            2 * (((x) - float(width) / 2) / float(width)) + ax, 2 * ((y - float(height)) / float(height)) - ay + 1.0f,
            2 * (((x) - float(width) / 2) / float(width)) + ax, 2 * ((y - float(height)) / float(height)) + ay + 1.0f,
            2 * (((x) - float(width) / 2) / float(width)) - ax, 2 * ((y - float(height)) / float(height)) + ay + 1.0f};
rotateVertices(vertices);
```

where:

- width - window width
- height - window height
- size - size of square

After calculation square looks normal for `angle=0`, but when I've checked ie. `angle=M_PI/4` which should rotate square 45 degrees, rotation applies with strange transformation of square to rectangle.(as shown in pictures)
[image: Squares rotation example]

Of course I would love to have the proportions kept, but I cannot think of the solution at the moment. If anybody could think of fast fix, or could point me in the correct direction I would be pleased.

Comment: Can't say I see anything wrong with your rotation. But your square is too big. When you rotate by 45° the corners will be outside the screen, are they maybe cropped back to be on screen and that disfigures the square?

Comment: Note: I would call `px` and `py` `cx` and `cy` for center. Using a `struct Vertice { float x, y; }` would also make the code more readable. Maybe even add a Matrix struct for the rotation that you compute once outside the loop and add +, -, * (scalar product), ^ (dot product) operators for them.

Comment: Please show a [mre]. Unless your window is square then your shape won't be square either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your square **is** a rectangle. My crystal ball knows this because its width and height are calculated separately, and therefore, you meant for them to be different:

```
// if you wanted these to be the same you wouldn't calculate them separately
float ay = (size / float(height) / 2.f), ax = (size / float(width) / 2.f);
```

The only reason it looks like a square is because the screen projection is also distorted to cancel it out.

When you rotate the rectangle they no longer cancel out.

You should draw a square with the same width and height, and then fix the matrices that convert the square into screen coordinates, so that when you render something with the same width and height it does get the same width and height on the screen.

Comment: Thank you, The problem was solved when I've made `ax` and `ay` the same. The proportion have been kept then and it solved my problem. I thought that the screen projection would cancel out the distorted vertices matrix of rectangle to keep it as square even if it would be rotated. Guess my assumption was wrong.